# react-native: Clear cache from inside the App programmatically (e.g. via Button-Click)

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to implement some kind of "clear cache" function in React-Native so the user could click a Button and the Application cache would be cleared?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this module https://github.com/midas-gufei/react-native-clear-app-cache

or implement cache deleting separately in native as per the requirement of your project (like my project needed just to get rid off of mp4s and pdfs)
Cached resources can be found at: 
ios: NSTemporaryDirectory()

```
  NSError *error;

  NSArray *directoryItems1 = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:NSTemporaryDirectory() error:&error];
  NSLog(@"%@, %@", directoryItems1, [directoryItems1 objectAtIndex:0]);


  if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[directoryItems1 objectAtIndex:0]])  //Does directory exist?
  {
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[directoryItems1 objectAtIndex:0] error:&error])  //Delete it
    {
      NSLog(@"Delete directory error: %@", error);
    }
  }
```

android: 
`

```
public void clearApplicationData()
    {
        File cache = getCacheDir();
        File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());
        if (appDir.exists()) {
            String[] test =  cache.list();
            Log.d("before", Arrays.toString(test));
            for (String s : test) {
                if (s.contains(".pdf") || s.contains(".mp4")) {
                    deleteDir(new File(cache, s));
                    Log.i("TAG", "**************** File /data/data/APP_PACKAGE/" + s + " DELETED *******************");
                }
            }
            Log.d("After delete", Arrays.toString(cache.list()));
        }
    }

public static boolean deleteDir(File dir)
{
    if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
    String[] children = dir.list();
    for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
        if (!success) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
    return dir.delete();
}`
```

Answer (score -1):

What kind of cache do you want to clean?
some application level cache?
If so - create the react-native native module and implement functionality you need.

or you want to do the same with:
npm start -- --reset-cache?
This is impossible to do out of the box.
But you might extend the react-native packager and add developer menu option to do so.